# Return results from full months

Tags: date, teradata, min

I currently have a dataset where the range of results span between the dates: `15-01-2017` to `30-04-2018`

So therefore, my `min(date)` would be `15-01-2017`.

However, I want to return results whereby if my `min(date)` is not a complete month, it should give me the results from next full month onwards (i.e.: `01-02-2017` to `30-04-2018`).

Hoping to get some direction

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the start of the next month unless it's the first of the month:

```
trunc(add_months(min(datecol)-1,1), 'mon')
```

Add one month to the day before the min date (i.e. only the 1st will result in the previous month), then get the 1st of that month.

Depending on your actual query you might filter using

```
qualify datecol >= trunc(add_months(min(datecol) over (partition by ??)-1,1), 'mon')
```